# Preventing internet access for smart devices using MAC filtering

Tags: internet, mac-address, mac-spoofing

If I use MAC filtering on my router to prevent internet access for a smart device e.g. IP camera, could it feasibly change the MAC address to get around this and leak data to a remote server? If so, what can robustly prevent internet access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices randomise their MAC on start up, and that's a trivial function, so that's a *feasible* scenario, though unlikely. Benign IoT devices don't tend to want to avoid detection or stable identification.

The best case is to set up a VLAN or a separate network for your IoT devices that blocks *all* outgoing traffic to the internet.